# How to make a Xaml VisibilityConverter default to false on load so nothing shows up at all?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-phone-8, converters

Because right now, if you make a VisibilityConverter, bind to false, it shows up in the UI when the app loads, then after half a second it disappears. Is there a trick to this working properly?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Just VisibilityConverters in general, found everywhere. If they're bound to a DependencyProperty defaulted to false, the objects still shows up in say a WP8 application for a split second, THEN it gets bound to the false and hides.

Edit: One like this - http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/super-duper-all-in-one-visibilityconverter-for-wpdev/

Comment: I never had the problem that you talk about. It would help to see how you use the converter in your code.

Comment: <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Yellow" Visibility="{Binding ShowRect, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />

Comment: If you do it like the rectangle above, when you first load a WP application, the rectangle will show up, then disappear. I guess since the ShowRect property doesn't exist yet on load.

Comment: I've seen this for 5 years, from Silverlight to WP7, WP8 to Windows 8 Store apps.

Comment: It would help to see how and at what point of the lifecycle your ShowRect property is assigned, how you declare and use the converter, what hardware you use, whether it's an emulator and you have outdated video drivers and so on. It could be a variety of factors.

Comment: @TrueHarlequin When are you assigning the datacontext to your page? If you do it in the constructor and before the call to `InitializeComponent`, it should work just fine

Comment: That did it KooKiz. I still had the old DataContext = App.ViewModel; and the binding happened after it loaded. Once I added the proper this.DataContext = this; it worked fine. I have a feeling I always saw this at the beginning of a project, and as it moved on, the DataContext got tied into real code and it worked properly and I forgot all about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The binding will only be resolved once the datacontext has been set. If you see the control briefly appear then disappear, it means that you've set the datacontext **after** the rendering of the page.

To prevent this issue, make absolutely sure that the datacontext is assigned before any control of the page is rendered. To be safe, I usually do that in the page contructor, before the call to `InitializeComponents`.

Comment: So binding on the main LayoutRoot Grid sounds like the wrong way to do it then as well. I usually set the datacontext of the grid to be the parent page or control. E.g. <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ControlRoot}">...it sounds like if I do it this way it's wrong too...